# how to fix this suspicious call to hashmap.get

Tags: java, hashmap

So this is my HashMap

```
HashMap<Literal, Double> literalHashMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Literal literal : literalHashSet) {
    if(literal.isTrue(node.state)){ literalHashMap.put(literal, 0.0);}
    else{literalHashMap.put(literal, Double.MAX_VALUE);}
}
```

Then I do this:

```
literalHashMap.put((Literal)proposition, updatedCost);
```

But when I do this:

```
cost += literalHashMap.get(proposition)
```

I see a warning saying "suspicious call to hashmap.get".

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's saying suspicious call because you pass a `Literal` Object as the key (`literalHashMap.put((Literal)proposition, updatedCost);` you downcast proposition so it becomes a `Literal` object). So, I can assume that `proposition` is not a `Literal` object. However, you pass `proposition` as the key to the `HashMap`, which is a different kind of object entirely. To fix this: `cost += literalHashMap.get((Literal) proposition);`. Or, to save a *tiny* bit of time:

```
Literal lit = (Literal) proposition;
literalHashMap.put((lit, updatedCost);
cost += literalHashMap.get(list);
```

To avoid downcasting twice.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while googling. IntelliJ can also create this warning when the key is defined as an `Object`.

For example, consider the following code.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = ImmutableMap.of("foo", "bar");
Object key = "key";
String val = myMap.get(key);
```

In the example above, even though `val` is set to `bar`, the `get()` call still results in a "suspicious call" warning.